# Web doesn't adjust WebView width in Android 4.0.X

Tags: android, web, webview

I've inserted the following sentence for adjusting my web to my WebView

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
```

I also inserted this in my code:

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

In my Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.2, it works pretty well and the web is adjusted to my WebView, but in my another mobile with Android 4.0.4 It doesn't work. Does anyone how I can solve it?

Comment: You need to use responsive design patterns for html to work well in browsers.

Comment: But On Android 4.4.2 it works well. What's the difference?